# KonvaJs: Ring with Angular Gradient

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, gradient, konvajs

I am using [KonvaJS](http://konvajs.github.io/docs/) in my project. I need to make ring or arc with the angular gradient. The way it is done in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/w46ps/). I used colors which are used in the fiddle with `Konva.Arc` like this

```
fillRadialGradientStartPoint: 0,
fillRadialGradientStartRadius: 35,
fillRadialGradientEndPoint: 0,
fillRadialGradientEndRadius: 55,
fillRadialGradientColorStops: [0, '#0F0', 1.0, '#0FF', 0, '#F00', 1.0, '#FF0', 0, '#F0F', 1.0, '#00F']
```

But I don't know what I am missing. I am not able to give it same look. Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iyWyUghfoAahkiDbbE5d?p=preview). In the plunkr, I have used a custom shape. With custom shape, I am able to draw the ring with angular gradient but I don't want to use custom shape cause if I use custom shape then I'll have to take care of other stuff as well and since Konva already has two inbuilt shapes `Konva.Ring` and `Konva.Arc`. So it would be better to use them.

[image: Expected ring]

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Done

Answer (score 2):

**The Konva.Image can use an html5 canvas as its image source.**

This means you can:

1. Create an in-memory canvas containing the arc-gradient (using the same code as [your linked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/w46ps/)).
2. Create a Konva.Image using the canvas from #1 as an image source.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 350,
  height: 350
});
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// create arc gradient on an in-memory canvas
var r=120;
var lw=30;
var c=drawMultiRadiantCircle(r,lw,['#0F0','#0FF','#F00','#FF0','#F0F']);

// use the in-memory canvas as an image source for Konva.Image
var img=new Konva.Image({x:0,y:0,image:c,width:c.width,height:c.height,draggable:true});
layer.add(img);
layer.draw();


// helper function: return a new canvas containing an arc-gradient
function drawMultiRadiantCircle(r, linewidth, radientColors) {
  var xc=r+linewidth/2;
  var yc=r+linewidth/2;
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width=r*2+linewidth;
  canvas.height=r*2+linewidth;
  var partLength = (2 * Math.PI) / radientColors.length;
  var start = 0;
  var gradient = null;
  var startColor = null;
  var endColor = null;
  //
  for (var i = 0; i < radientColors.length; i++) {
    startColor = radientColors[i];
    endColor = radientColors[(i + 1) % radientColors.length];
    // x start / end of the next arc to draw
    var xStart = xc + Math.cos(start) * r;
    var xEnd = xc + Math.cos(start + partLength) * r;
    // y start / end of the next arc to draw
    var yStart = yc + Math.sin(start) * r;
    var yEnd = yc + Math.sin(start + partLength) * r;
    gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, startColor);
    gradient.addColorStop(1.0, endColor);
    //
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = gradient;
    ctx.arc(xc, yc, r, start, start + partLength);
    ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    start += partLength;
  }
  return(canvas);
}
```

```css
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/0.9.0/konva.min.js"></script>
<h4>A draggable Konva.Image created from an html5 canvas.</h4>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer markE. But I am not getting, why you are making it much complicated. I mean if we can make it working by using the radial and linear gradient properties of Konva.Ring and Konva.Arc. can it be done using these properties?

Comment: You can't make an arc gradient using a single radial or linear gradient. The radial gradient moves from center outward and the linear gradient moves in a non-circular path. :-)

Comment: Ok got it. What if I need to draw an arc not the whole ring. I mean currently in your fiddle you are drawing it for entire ring. But I need to draw it to an angle n.

Comment: `partLength` determines how much of the complete 2*PI of a circle is rendered with the gradient. So if you instead want an arc of `n` radians you can adjust it like this: `partLength *= n/(Math.PI*2)`. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Ok. I'll try it. Thank you very much. :)